# Sources for Large Dataset to practise Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

am just starting out at Hadoop. I would like to practise coding Hadoop on home computer. Can anyone tell me how i can get datasets in magnitude of Gigabytes to start practising?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a compilation of datasets from Data Science Central:

http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/big-data-sets-available-for-free